# Discrete representation of derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

In the process of implementing a differential feedback loop, I read the following expression in my textbook:
\begin{align}
y(t_i) &= e(t_i) - e(t_{i-1}) \\
&= \frac{e(t_i)+3e(t_{i-1}) - 3e(t_{i-2}) - e(t_{i-3})}{6} \ ,
\end{align}
without any justification on the second equality whatsoever.

The expression is supposed to be a discrete respresentation of the time derivative $y(t) = \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{dt}}e(t).$

How does one arrive at this particular discrete representation of the a time derivative?

Comment: You can approximate the derivative with a difference quotient, and then a Taylor series produces the approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be very surprised if your textbook does not use equidistant points, i.e. $$t_i = a + ih.$$
Then by Taylor's theorem
$$ e(t_{i-1}) = e(t_i) + e'(t_i)(t_{i-1} - t_i) + \frac{1}{2}e''(\xi)(t_{i-1} - t_i)^2, $$
for at least one $\xi$ between $t_{i-1}$ and $t_i$. Using the notation $e_i = e(t_i)$ and identifying $y$ with the derivative $e'$ we can express this equation as
$$ e_{i-1} = e_i - y_i h + \frac{1}{2} e''(\xi) h^2$$
It follows that
$$ y_i = \frac{e_i - e_{i-1}}{h} + \frac{1}{2} e''(\xi) h.$$
Given the context, i.e. a feedback loop, I am not at all surprised that the time step is unity, i.e. $h=1$, leaving us with
$$ y_i = e_i - e_{i-1} + \frac{1}{2} e''(\xi),$$
which is very nearly the equation given in your text. However, in general, it is impossible to drop the error term, i.e. $\frac{1}{2} e''(\xi)$. I suspect the surrounding texts explains that higher order terms have been dropped. It might also be that they have written either
$$y_i \approx e_i - e_{i-1}$$
or
$$y_i \,\dot{=}\, e_i - e_{i-1}$$
to indicate that expressions are approximations rather than exact equalities.

---

As for the second expression, repeated application of Taylor's formula yields
\begin{align*}
e_{i-1} &= e_i -  h y_i + \frac{1}{2} e''_i h^2 + O(h^3), \\
e_{i-2} &= e_i - 2h y_i + \frac{1}{2} e''_i (2h)^2 + O(h^3), \\
e_{i-3} &= e_i - 3h y_i + \frac{1}{2} e''_i (3h)^2 + O(h^3).
\end{align*}
Here I have expanded a bit more and I am only tracking the order of the error term. It follows that
$$ e_i + 3 e_{i-1} - 3e_{i-2} - e_{i-3} = 0\cdot e_i + 6h y_i + 0\cdot e''_i + O(h^3),$$
which implies
$$ y_i = \frac{ e_i + 3 e_{i-1} - 3e_{i-2} - e_{i-3}}{6h} + O(h^2).$$
If $h=1$ and if the higher order terms are ignored, then you arrive at the expression in your textbook.

The relevant technical term is *one-sided* finite difference approximations.

Comment: How can there be a $\xi$ between $t_{i-1}$ and $t_{i}$? Why not just write $e''(t_i)$ in the Taylor expansion of $e(t_{i-1})$?

Comment: I am quoting one of several versions of Taylor's theorem which gives a formula for the error term. I can not be sure, but I believe you are confusing Taylor's formula with a truncated Taylor expansion.

Comment: I see. In that case, use of $\xi \in [t_{i-1}, t_i] $ doesn't make any sense, since we're using equidistant points; as opposed to a continuous interval.